# How to download dbgsym kernel for 15.10?

Tags: kernel, debug

I have an issue trying to find the dbgsym kernel from the ww repositories.
Unfortunately i cannot find it. My system crashes when running wine and chrome and i am trying to read the crash dump.

```
uname -r
4.2.0-25-generic

sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic-dbgsym
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic-     dbgsym'

sudo apt-cache search generic-dbgsym | grep kernel
linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic-dbgsym - Linux kernel debug image for     version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.2.0-19-generic-dbgsym - Linux kernel debug image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.2.0-21-generic-dbgsym - Linux kernel debug image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.2.0-18-generic-dbgsym - Linux kernel debug image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic-dbgsym - Linux kernel debug image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-4.2.0-24-generic-dbgsym - Linux kernel debug image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-image-3.19.0-23-generic-dbgsym - Linux kernel debug image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ wily main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ wily-security main restricted universe  multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ wily-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Also i tried to clean the repo lists just in case something funky is going on there but i still seem to get the errors bellow. I cleaned them using 
sudo software-properties-gtk

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `apt-get update` and attempting to install again.

Looking at:
http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/

I see that particular dbgsym package is available as of today.

Comment: Weird... it appears now in the repos!! I guess it needed some time, thanks!

Comment: Do you know by any chance why these 404 errors appear?